# CSSセレクタでXpathのように属性に直接アクセスできる記述方法

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Nokogiriを使い、`img`タグの`src`要素にアクセスする時に xpathなら

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<img src='foo.jpg' />")
doc.xpath("//img/@src")
```

で属性自体を直接指定できるのですが、cssセレクタですと

```
doc.css("img").attr("src")
```

という呼び出し方しか見つかりませんでした。属性名をCSSセレクタだけで呼び出す方法はありますか？

Comment: CSSセレクタでは無理ではないかと思ったのですが、どのようなケースでそういう呼び出しが必要になるのでしょうか？

Comment: cssセレクタで呼び出せるなら、`attr`メソッドを使わず簡潔にできるのであるなら知りたく質問いたしました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

厳密にはCSSセレクタではないと思いますが、`css` メソッドで取り出したいというだけであれば、

```
doc.css("img/@src")
```

で取り出すことができるようです。

Comment: あれ、、この記法は試して動かなかったと思ったんですが今やってみると問題なく動きました。何か間違えていたようです。ありがとうございます。